# how to use axios with this body n js

Tags: javascript, axios

I have trouble post with axios
my post body is :

```
{
    "action": "createRoom",
    "params": {
        "name": "cloud-services",
        "title":"test",
        "max_users": 50,
        "guest_login": true
    }
}
```

And I use axios it like this :

```
  async createClassInSkyRoom({ action = "createRoom", name, title, max_users, guest_login }) {
    const result = await instance().post(Constants.URL_SKYROOM, { action, params: { name, title, max_users, guest_login } })
    return result
  }
```

and my instance is  :

```
module.exports = () => {
  const instance = axios.create({})
  return instance
}
```

And I get the following error :‌

```
 err: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
      --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
      |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
      --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
      at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
      at stringify (/home/firefly/Desktop/project/taha-m/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1128:12)
      at ServerResponse.json (/home/firefly/Desktop/project/taha-m/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
      at ResponseHandler.send (/home/firefly/Desktop/project/taha-m/app/Handler/ResponseHandler.js:9:26)
      at ClassController.goToClassOnSkyRoom (/home/firefly/Desktop/project/taha-m/app/Class/class.controller.js:62:28)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right request. Thank you all

```
  async createClassInSkyRoom({ action = "createRoom", name, title, max_users, guest_login }) {
    const result = await instance().post(Constants.URL_SKYROOM, data:{ action, params: { name, title, max_users, guest_login }})
    return result
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tride to change
`const result = await instance().post(Constants.URL_SKYROOM, { action, params: { name, title, max_users, guest_login } })` to
`const result = await instance.post(Constants.URL_SKYROOM, { action, params: { name, title, max_users, guest_login } })`.
I think you don't need to run instace directly

Comment: thank you but Not for instance . and i think this problem for Not used properly body and params